# Why? - Win 8.1 chkdsk runs each bootup against hidden 450MB recovery partition

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, chkdsk, system-reserved-partition

This problem won't be easy...be warned.
Windows 8.1 x64 (installed as Windows 8.1, not as an upgrade) with ALL updates installed and working perfectly (as per event log viewer) ...two days ago.
There were no updates that didn't get installed improperly nor that the system shutdown incorrectly.

Mysteriously each bootup, the hidden Windows RE partition (partition #5 at end of disk) keeps being checked and supposedly repaired as shown by quick onscreen message, albeit very quickly on an known good SSD (perfect SMART values).

The partitions in physical order are:
Partition 1: Recovery 300MB 1024kb offset
Partition 2: System 100MB 302MB offset
Partition 3: Reserved 128MB 402MB
Partition 4: * Primary 930GB 536MB offset
Partition 5: Recovery 450MB 931GB offset

Event log shows:
A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume \?\Volume{20e356e9-c78d-47ea-8fb9-7297d5c10082}. [Partition 5:]

A file on the volume is no longer reachable from its parent directory.  The parent file reference number is 0x2000000000002.  The name of the parent directory is "".  The parent index attribute is ":$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".  The file reference number of the file that needs to be reconnected is 0x100000003cbff.  There may be additional files on the volume that also need to be reconnected to this parent directory.

Assign drive letter D: to RE partition and no errors while viewing contents but FSutil query reports dirty volume.
Run Admin chkdsk (with myriads of various parameters) against D: and it reports nothing wrong, no bad sectors either.
Running Recovery command line option and same chkdsk responses - all is well, still FSutil reports dirty.
Through all this, the registry autocheck autochk data eventually became autocheck autochk /k:D
Since then, I returned that registry setting to a normal autocheck autochk *
Normally, the Windows RE partition is not mounted via drive letter, which is how I'd like it to stay, after all this is fixed.

Other command results:
fsutil repair enumerate d: (shows no corruption logs)
fsutil repair query d: (shows Self healing state on d: is: 0x9, Enable repair and warn about potential data loss.)
fsutil repair state d: (shows "Corruption State:  0x11 - Full Chkdsk Needed"

Run chkdsk again with parameters from A to Z and no reported problems, either logically or physically.

Obviously, something is wrong, even the Action Center says "Whoaa...run full system chkdsk, dude, corruption abounds" yeah right, shut up Action Center.

And to top if off, any restore points failed, so I eventually wiped them all out, wondering if they were the cause. NOT.

Otherwise, the system runs like a top and no corruption seems present in programs/data/etc.

Any ideas out there.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem and here's how;

First, changed UEFI settings by turning off secure boot and changed to "CSM/UEFI" mode - just in case. Boot into the laptop.

(While Windows 8.1 was now running) 
I made an image of the hidden WinRe partition (which contains the recovery environment .wim file among others) saving it to c: drive.

Then I used a partition utility program to wipe the RE partition (partition #5) with zeros.
Next I used same utility to delete the partition so it became free space.
Now I rebooted.

Windows 8.1 x64 rebooted without any error messages or problems FINALLY!

Return to partition utility to create an NTFS GPT partition taking all available free space at end of disk (450MB). Somehow the utility remembered the partition was named "OEM service volume" (strange but accepted)

Using the partition utility, mounted the saved partition to obtain access to the files inside.
Used the utility again to COPY the files/folders into the newly created empty 450MB partition. Do not restore the partition, simply copy the contents.

I did notice and exclude from copying a "system volume information" folder which should of not been in there and may have contributed to original problem.
Exiting the program,  rebooted.
No chkdsk errors upon bootup - great!

Once booted,  tested normal user access to recovery options from advanced startup. 
Looks like the recovery environment is accessible and working correctly,  although I did not refresh,  reinstall,  or restore Windows.

Lastly, reboot into UEFI options, choose secure boot and UEFI setting and Fast Boot.

The work above was basically recreating the Windows recovery environment partition manually. Hope someone gets some mileage from this.